# My method doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, function, methods, logic

I'm working on a program that assigns people to missions through the day.

For 8 hours, I've been struggling to figure out whats wrong with my method. It 
should take a list of names, a list of missions, and a 24 hours counter, and assign each person to a mission at hour X. If that mission requires more than one person, it will try to assign the next one too (if there isn't any condition that prevents that person from being assigned to the mission).

After all the people in the list have been assigned, the program should reset the list of people to be assigned, and start assigning them again.

When I run my code, there is only 1 round of assigning and the rest of the table is left blank.

I tried figuring out whats wrong with the logic, but I just cant and it's SO FRUSTRATING!! So please help me out here!

The code:

```
public string[,] AssignPersonsToMission()
{
    bool containCondition; // any item of Person.Conditions is in mission.Conditions?
    int assignedCounter = 0; // how many people assigned to a mission at given hour
    string[,] table = new string[missions.Count, 24]; // columns = missions, rows = hour of day
    List<Person> personsToAssign = persons; // filling list with people to assign
    List<Person> assignedPersons = new List<Person>(); // a list of people that have been assigned

    for (int mission = 0; mission < missions.Count; mission++) //go throught columns
    {
        for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++) //go through rows
        {
            if (personsToAssign.Count == 0) //if all the people have been assigned to missions
            {
                personsToAssign = persons; // refill personsToAssign list with original list of people
                assignedPersons.Clear(); // reset assigned Persons list
            } 
            assignedCounter = 0; // reset assignedCounter
            foreach (Person person in personsToAssign.ToList()) //go through each person that can be assigned
            {
                containCondition = missions[mission].Conditions.Intersect(person.Conditions).Any(); // is there any condition in mission that the person has? 
                                                                                                    //if yes - that person cannot be assigned to the mission
                if (!containCondition)
                {
                    table[mission, hour] += person.Name + "|"; //put person in mission at a given hour
                    assignedPersons.Add(person); //add the person to a list of assigned people
                    personsToAssign.Remove(person);//remove the person from the list of people to assign
                    assignedCounter++;//increament how many people assigned to this mission at this hour

                    if (assignedCounter < missions[mission].NumOfPeople) //if not enough people have been assigned to the mission
                    {
                        continue; //go to the next person to assign
                    }
                    else { break; }//go the the next hour

                }// END OF if (!containCondition)

            }//END OF foreach (Person person in personsToAssign.ToList())

        }//END OF  for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++)


    }//END OF for (int mission = 0; mission < missions.Count; mission++)

    return table;
}
```

Comment: You should really consider to choose a title that summarizes the specific problem. So that other people can find your post when they encounter the same problem. [Help] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is here

Comment: So when you step through with the debugger, can't you tell why the table isn't getting populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing your original list `persons`

Change this:

```
List<Person> personsToAssign = persons;
```

to:

```
List<Person> personsToAssign = new List<Person> (persons);
```

You are not making a copy of the list, you just set a reference to it. So if you remove a person from `personsToAssign`, you also remove it from `persons` since both variables point to the same list in memory.